# Discipline of the Slaughter interaction with Flicker Strike

Tags: path-of-exile

Can frenzy charge from passive skill [`discipline of the slaughter`](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Disciple_of_the_Slaughter) be used to bypass flicker strike cool down, or it is unusable?

Comment: Neither discipline or slaughter give frenzy charges? I'm not sure what you're trying to say with your question

Comment: @FoxMcCloud sorry, typo in name. I'm speaking about passive tree node. Added link to wiki to be more clear. It adds +1 to minimum frenzy charges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skills and effects that consume charges to activate an effect cannot use these minimum charges. For example, using Flicker Strike with +1 to Minimum Frenzy Charges at 1 Frenzy charge will never use that charge to remove its cooldown.

[SOURCE](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Charge)

Comment: I know about generation chance, it works pretty obvious. My question is not about chance, it is about +1 to *MINIMUM* charges. So you always have 1 instead of 0. So could this one be used by flicker or it is only granting constant frenzy bonus, scaling with all frenzy bonus modifiers from tree and items (such as even more speed, evasion, etc.)

Comment: It does both, grants constant bonuses and then doesn't once you use it with flicker.

Comment: But text says, that +1 to minimum, so if base is zero, you just *cannot* have zero with this passive, you ALWAYS have one, because it is minimum number of charges

Comment: @TEXHIK Stand by, I found the answer. Editing my answer for you.